# Example where $H_1 (X, A) \not\cong H_1 (X / A)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm trying to get a better understanding of relative homology, and I have a hard time visualizing the distinction between $H_1(X,A)$ and $H_1(X/A)$. I assume there's no way they are equal (otherwise why even define $H(X,A)$), but I can't come up with an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $X=S^1$ and let $A=S^1\setminus\{p\}$ for some point $p\in S^1$.  Then $A$ is contractible, so $H_1(X,A)\cong H_1(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}$.  However, the quotient space $X/A$ has only two points, and in fact is contractible (that's a nice exercise).  So $H_1(X/A)$ is trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the simple example, some quick followup questions. Is it a general fact that $H_n (X,A) \cong H_n(X)$ when $A$ is contractible? Is it because $C_n (X) / C_n (A)$ has to be the same as $C_n (X)$ if $A$ is contractible, since all the chains in $A$ can be reduced to one point anyway? And finally am I right we only really need that $X/A$ has 2 points (so all the loops are trivial), the contractibility isn't necessary?

Comment: You can use the long exact sequence of the pair to show that $H_n(X,A)\cong H_n(X)$ for $n\geq 1$, when $A$ is contractible.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip You're right, thanks.

Comment: It is emphatically not true that $C_n(X)/C_n(A)$ is the same as $C_n(X)$.  All chains in $A$ can in some sense be "reduced to a point", but that doesn't make them equal to $0$ in $C_n(X)$.

Comment: You have to do some real work to show that $H_1(X/A)$ is trivial; the fact that it has two points doesn't tell you anything automatically.  For instance, there exists a space $Y$ with only four points such that $H_1(Y)$ is nontrivial.

Comment: @EricWofsey Welp, there goes any little intuition i thought i might have about this. Interesting that a discrete space can be so weird.

Comment: It's _not_ a discrete space.  Discrete spaces always have trivial homology in positive dimensions (and that is more or less trivial), but not all finite spaces are discrete!

Comment: @EricWofsey Yeah sorry, by discrete i meant the set not the topology. Should have phrased it differently.

Comment: @TheMountainThatCodes, those finite topologies really are counter-intuitive.

Comment: @TheMountainThatCodes: For more fun with finite spaces, consider the following example: Let $X$ be the space with only three points $a_1,b,a_2$ such that each $a_i$ is closed, and let $A=\{a_1,a_2\}$. Then $X$ is contractible, so $H_1(X,A) \cong \tilde H_0(A)$, and since $A$ is disconnected, this group is non-trivial. The homology groups of $X/A$, however, are trivial, since that space is contractible.